# How to solve circular dependency without creating new package?

Tags: go, package, circular-dependency

In golang want a plugins system with a global registry. Structure can be simplified as follows:

```
/plugins/registry.go
/plugins/plugin1/impl.go
```

registry.go:

```
package plugins

import "plugins/plugin1" // required for plugin1.MakePlugin

type IPlugin interface {
  Register() error
}

type Factory func(x int) IPlugin

var registry = []Factory{
  plugin1.MakePlugin,
}
```

impl.go:

```
package plugin1

import "plugins" // required for IPlugin

type Plugin struct {
  x int
}

func MakePlugin(x int) plugins.IPlugin {
  return &Plugin{
    x: x,
  }
}
```

How to solve without moving `IPlugin` to 3rd (e.g `common`) package?

PS. I thought if i return `*Plugin` from `MakePlugin` this will be compatible with Factory, but its not!!!

Comment: Put everything in one package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*"How to solve without moving `IPlugin` to 3rd (e.g `common`) package?"*

You have at least two options:

1. move the registration to a 3rd (e.g. `main`) package.
2. have each plugin register itself when imported by some other package.

---

Example #1

```golang
package plugins

type IPlugin interface {
  Register() error
}

type Factory func(x int) IPlugin

var registry []Factory

func Register(ff ...Factory) {
    registry = append(registry, ff...)
}
```

```golang
package main

import (
    "plugins"
    "plugins/plugin1"
)

func init() {
    plugins.Register(plugin1. MakePlugin)
}

func main() {
    // ...
}
```

---

Example #2

```golang
package plugins

type IPlugin interface {
  Register() error
}

type Factory func(x int) IPlugin

var registry []Factory

func Register(ff ...Factory) {
    registry = append(registry, ff...)
}
```

```golang
package plugin1

import "plugins" // required for IPlugin

func init() {
    plugins.Register(MakePlugin)
}

type Plugin struct {
  x int
}

func MakePlugin(x int) plugins.IPlugin {
  return &Plugin{
    x: x,
  }
}
```

```golang
package main

import (
    "plugins"
    _ "plugins/plugin1" // will execute init() i.e. register
)

func main() {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to separate the Interfaces from their implementation to external packages that are abstract. Then, depend on them according to the [Dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and [Adapter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) paradigms.